# A Mystical Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

Here is another Riley Riddle:

> The prefix is us together
>
> The infix you see twice
>
> The suffix indefinitely used before a vowel

**What am I?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Wiccan

The prefix is us together

> **Wi** - sounds like we

The infix you see twice

> **cc** - the letter 'c' twice

The suffix indefinitely used before a vowel

> **an** - the indefinite article used before vowels

Title

> A wiccan is an adherent to Pagan witchcraft

Answer (score 2):

you are

> Wiccan

The prefix is us together

> We (or Wi)

The infix you see twice

> cc (C twice)

The suffix indefinitely used before a vowel

> An, used before a vowel